# Submitting a form data in to grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

Inputs needed on binding a form to a Gridview

Answer (score 1):

I think you need tutorial which shows how the data get insert, edit for gridview than you can google it or you can see this example which ehlp you to move further

[ASP.Net GridView- Insert Edit Update and Delete the ADO.NET way](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASP.Net-GridView--Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-the-ADO.NET-way.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Create database table to update your text box data
2. Write code to properly update the database
3. Bind gridview into the table.

Then when you save the data it will show on the data grid view.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i have already created database , you have any sample code or or any example related to that